# Why can't I access `userService` variable after express instance running in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I was trying to create an endpoint in node.js, more specifically in express
but I am not sure why I can't access `userService` variable when requesting from a client.

I've gotten `Cannot read property 'userService' of undefined`, but when i move `ServicesFactory.getInstance().getUserService()` inside the `signUp` function it works?!
I am guessing that node.js garbage collects it due to it's not being used until the user make a request.

```
export class UserApi implements WebEndpoint {

    router: Router
    userService = ServicesFactory.getInstance().getUserService()

    constructor() {
        this.router = Router()
        this.router.post('/signup', this.signUp)
    }

    signUp(req: Request, res: Response): void {
        const user: User = req.body
        this.userService.signUp(user)
        res.send("Successfully registered")
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call `signUp` from your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, so basically I am a noob.
consider this example

```
class a {
    constructor() {
        this.a1 = 'hello';
    }

    greet(){
        const greeting = `${this.a1} dude!`;
        console.log(greeting);
    };
}

class b {
    b1 = new a();

    constructor() {
        this.b1.greet.call();
    }
}

new b();
```

Now it wouldn't run, because `b` class called `greet` method with a new context, the same with express when you provide a function as a handler on an Express endpoint it will be called with a new set of context (read:`this`) that's why `this.userService` in my code above won't work because there is no `userService` property in the context provided by Express.

The solution is simple. Arrow function.

```
 signUp = (req: Request, res: Response): void => {
        const user: User = req.body
        this.userService.signUp(user)
        res.send("Successfully registered")
    }
```

Now the function will inherit it's class's context.You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/6918296) for more detail answer.